# Angular - Can a child component reference a parent's template variable?

Tags: angular, primeng

I am working on an angular 4 application using a primefaces primeng component, `p-contextmenu`. I am trying to tell a child element to use a template variable of a parent component.

app.html:

```
<div>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <div #contextMenuHolder></div>
</div>
```

mycomponent.html:

```
<p-contextMenu [appendTo]="contextMenuHolder" [model]="items"></p-contextMenu>
```

Obviously it fails as the `contextMenuHolder` does not exist in the child, but in its parent:

> Angular: Identifier 'contextMenuHolder' is not defined. The component declaration, template variable declarations, and element references do not contain such a member

Can you reference a parent's template variable from a child component?

Edit:

[Plunkr with it broken](https://plnkr.co/edit/R5ePgaPymE9N3FnmsKP6). This plunkr shows it not working, but no error messages.

Comment: Please correct your tags... read their info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for `appendTo` says

> Target element to attach the overlay, valid values are "body" or a local ng-template variable of another element.

Maybe a service can resolve the issue :

```
@Injectable()
export class ContextMenuHolder {
  contextMenu: any; // TODO set a type (HTMLElement?)

  getContextMenu() {
    return this.contextMenu;
  }

  setContextMenu(contextMenu: any) {
    this.contextMenu = contextMenu;
  }
}
```

In your `app.ts`, you inject the service and set the value.
In your `component.ts`, you inject the service and get the value.

I did not tested it but it *should* work. If the `contextMenu` can change, you will have to use event listeners or observable.

Comment: This gives me this error: `Cannot append [object Object] to [object HTMLDivElement]`

Comment: A bit of extra work, https://plnkr.co/edit/kwnkSKDPFs1Bp2xOHqIu?p=preview

Comment: @Jeff I messing with that `Cannot append [object Object] to [object HTMLDivElement]` you mentioned before. For some reason when I set in service `<div #holder></div>` from app-root-component all works ok. But when I use holder from any nested from root component this error occurs. Have you any thoughts about way to get rid of an error?

Comment: Not of the top of my head, but post another question and link it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Ludovic Guillaume I was able to find a solution:

https://plnkr.co/edit/kwnkSKDPFs1Bp2xOHqIu

child.ts:

```
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import {ContextMenuHolderService} from './context-menu-holder.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'child-comp',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello child</h2>
      <span #mySpan>this bit has a context menu</span> <br>
      <span #parentSpan>this bit is the target for the parent span.</span>

      <p-contextMenu [target]="mySpan" [appendTo]="parentContext" [model]="items"></p-contextMenu>
      <p-contextMenu [target]="parentSpan" [appendTo]="parentContext" [model]="itemsForParent"></p-contextMenu>
    </div>
  `,
})

export class ChildComponent {
  private items: MenuItem[];
  parentContext: any;

   constructor(private cmhs : ContextMenuHolderService) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.items = [{ label: 'mySpans context menu' }];
      this.itemsForParent =  [{ label: 'parent context menu items' }];
      console.log('child init', this.cmhs.getContextMenuParent())
      this.parentContext = this.cmhs.getContextMenuParent().nativeElement;
    }
}
```

Here, the child component has built the context menu with the items it wants in the menu. This menu needs to reside in the parent (sometimes this is necessary for styling or positioning reasons). The child has a `parentContext` object that will be set during it's `onInit` phase of the lifecycle.

parent (app.ts):

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION, ViewChild} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import {ChildComponent} from './child'
import {ContextMenuModule,MenuItem} from 'primeng/primeng'
import {ContextMenuHolderService} from './context-menu-holder.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <div #parentContextTarget>This is in the parent component and should have a context menu</div>
      <div #parentContextWrapper></div>
      <child-comp></child-comp>
    </div>
  `,
})


export class App {
  name:string;
  @ViewChild('parentContextWrapper') parentContextWrapper;

  constructor(private cmhs : ContextMenuHolderService) {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
    // console.log('parent constructor')
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    console.log('parent init - parent context wrapper', this.parentContextWrapper)
    this.cmhs.setContextMenuParent(this.parentContextWrapper)
  }


}
```

The parent sets the object in the service during it's `onInit` stage. Initially I thought this had to be during the `afterViewInit`, but this ended up being too late in the lifecycle.

service:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ContextMenuHolderService {
  contextMenuParent: any; // TODO set a type (HTMLElement?)

  getContextMenuParent() {
    console.log('returning cmp', this.contextMenuParent)
    return this.contextMenuParent;
  }

  setContextMenuParent(contextMenuParent: any) {
    console.log('settin context menu parent', contextMenuParent)
    this.contextMenuParent = contextMenuParent;
  }
}
```

Comment: Only odd issue I see... two context menus can be up at the same time.

Comment: Thanks!
If somebody finds this answer and is having problems with the error "Cannot append [object Object] to [object HTMLDivElement]", the solution is to use .nativeElement, like described in this answer.

Comment: @jgosar create a new question. I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: It's not a new question, i just wanted to point out that a Google search for "Cannot append [object Object] to [object HTMLDivElement]" brought me here and that the solution is already there in your answer, if you know where to look :)