# Angular overlayPanel problem with primeng

Tags: angular, primeng

In my angular 7 project I am using [primeng](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/) but I have an issue inside an overlay panel.

I have a table and when I click in a button on the table I need to show an overlayPanel with an input inside, but for some reason the input is not working ( I can't write into).
this is the overlay:

```
<p-overlayPanel #filterModel appendTo="body">
  <input type="text" />
</p-overlayPanel>
```

After some test I see that if I remove the `appendTo="body"` the input is working but the overlay is not in the correct position.

So how can I solve this?

Probably I am missing something, In this example If I switch the reference in the `appendTo` nothing change, and the overly is in the same position.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-template-ovproblem

Comment: Why don't you attach to `ng-template` and style accordingly?

Comment: like this? `<p-overlayPanel #filter [appendTo]="o2">`
`<ng-template #o2>ABC</ng-tempate>`
because I have an error

Comment: yes like this, what's the error in this case?

Comment: `Cannot append [object Object] to [object HTMLDivElement]`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45745607/angular-can-a-child-component-reference-a-parents-template-variable Might help you

Comment: sorry but I am missing something, I see the same ovelayPanel in the same position also If I change the appendTo property
https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-template-ovproblem